# how send attachmet in magento2 email

Tags: magento2

i want to send attachment in email its csv formatted file how i can achieve this in magento2?

Answer (score 0):

please refer this link to send attachment in mail -  [link](https://bsscommerce.com/blog/magento-2-attach-pdf-to-invoice-email/#:%7E:text=How%20To%20Attach%20PDF%20File%20To%20Magento%202%20Invoice%20Email%20Programmatically,-Magento%202%20uses&text=Then%20create%20the%20SenderBuilder%20class,or%20calendar%20files%20with%20email.&text=Finally%2C%20you%20add%20the%20following,%2FModule%2Fetc%2Fdi.).

Comment: Please try to add more information from the link you posted into your answer. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer